# Kazam always record only 1/4 of the screen

Tags: display-resolution, scaling, desktop-recording, kazam

I'm trying to use Kazam to take videos of the screen. It always records the 1/4 of top left of my screen, no matter what I do. No matter if I select the entire screen, a window or select a piece of the screen to record.

I guess it has to do with scaling. I use scaling in my ubuntu because it's a 4k monitor. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Kazam.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/kazam/+bug/1283424

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, has to do with the scaling configuration of your monitor. I also have a 4K and I need to use 200% scaling.

[This patch](https://mlisi.xyz/post/kazam/) solves the issue, it's very simple to apply. I tested it on Ubuntu 22.04.1 and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm patching it works on ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

Found the same issue on the kazam github https://github.com/hzbd/kazam/pull/47.

@sllorente prepared the path for 1 file only (instead of 2) which fixes the issue, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/kazam/+bug/1283424/comments/13

The patch can be downloaded from https://bugs.launchpad.net/kazam/+bug/1283424/+attachment/5499618/+files/kazam-1.4.5-patch

```patch
--- kazam-1.4.5/backend/prefs.py    2014-08-18 18:48:36.000000000 +0200
+++ kazam/backend/prefs.py  2021-05-23 15:30:44.876596507 +0200
@@ -312,22 +312,31 @@
             self.default_screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
             self.logger.debug("Found {0} monitor(s).".format(self.default_screen.get_n_monitors()))
 
+            combined_width = 0
+            combined_height = 0
             for i in range(self.default_screen.get_n_monitors()):
                 rect = self.default_screen.get_monitor_geometry(i)
-                self.logger.debug("  Monitor {0} - X: {1}, Y: {2}, W: {3}, H: {4}".format(i,
+                scale = self.default_screen.get_monitor_scale_factor(i)
+
+                self.logger.debug("  Monitor {0} - X: {1}, Y: {2}, W: {3}, H: {4}, scale: {5}".format(i,
                                                                                           rect.x,
                                                                                           rect.y,
                                                                                           rect.width,
-                                                                                          rect.height))
-                self.screens.append({"x": rect.x,
-                                     "y": rect.y,
-                                     "width": rect.width,
-                                     "height": rect.height})
+                                                                                          rect.height,
+                                                                                          scale))
+                self.screens.append({"x": rect.x * scale,
+                                     "y": rect.y * scale,
+                                     "width": rect.width * scale,
+                                     "height": rect.height * scale,
+                                     "scale": scale})
+
+                combined_width = combined_width + rect.width * scale
+                combined_height = combined_height + rect.height *scale
 
             if self.default_screen.get_n_monitors() > 1:
                 self.combined_screen = {"x": 0, "y": 0,
-                                        "width": self.default_screen.get_width(),
-                                        "height": self.default_screen.get_height()}
+                                        "width": combined_width,
+                                        "height": combined_height}
                 self.logger.debug("  Combined screen - X: 0, Y: 0, W: {0}, H: {1}".format(self.default_screen.get_width(),
                                                                                           self.default_screen.get_height()))
             else:
```

FYI the file can be patched with the command

```
sudo patch /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/prefs.py < ~/Desktop/kazam-1.4.5.diff
```

Comment: This works nicely on Ubuntu LTS 20.04.